# Unable to install ansible error is no package ansible available .nothing to do installing in redhat 7

Tags: ansible-2.x

Unable to install ansible on red hat 7 . No package ansible avialable error nothing to do

Comment: Kindly revert me

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Unfortunately, Red Hat recently moved Ansible (and some other Devops tools) to their extras repository that requires a subscription. However, we are adding another repository to our configuration that will restore access to it. We are in the process of refreshing our servers right now, in the interim, you can do the following:

1. Create a new file called 'ansible.repo' in /etc/yum.repos.d
2. Copy the following content into it:

[Ansible]

name = ansible

baseurl = https://releases.ansible.com/ansible/rpm/release/epel-7-x86_64/

enabled = 1

gpgcheck = 0
3. Run 'yum update'
4. Install ansible ('sudo yum install ansible') 
5. Successed